# How to discard local commits in Git?

Tags: git, git-reset

I'd been working on something, and decided it was completely screwed...after having committed some of it. So I tried the following sequence:

```
git reset --hard
git rebase origin
git fetch
git pull
git checkout
```

At which point I got the message

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

**I want to discard my local commits**, without having to wipe out my local directory and redownload everything. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: There is no need to do both `git fetch` and `git pull` -- pull is a combination of fetch and merge.

Comment: Note to users: the main problem of this question **has nothing to do with the message "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by N commits."**. Please stop closing other questions as duplicates of this one because of that message.

Answer (score 732, accepted):

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

will remove all commits not in `origin/master` where `origin` is the repo name and `master` is the name of the branch.

Comment: I thought the syntax "origin/master", with a slash, referred to a local repo?

Comment: mipadi: More correctly put, it will reset the current branch to point to the same commit as origin/master.

Comment: It refers to a branch. `origin/master` is a branch that tracks the `master` branch of the `origin` remote repo.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral No, `origin/master` is a reference to the `master` branch of the remote called `origin`.

Comment: In my own branch I create a new folder inside my project, and commit it but not push. Then I checkout to master. I want to create a new branch without that folder. So I use this command, and the file which master already had before become back to consistent with master. But that new folder which master doesn't had before still there. And "git status" in master told me it's clean. What should I do?

Comment: @littletiger git does not track folders, only files and their paths. Therefore, it will completely ignore empty folders (folders with no files, or only ignored files). They don't show up anywhere as there is nothing to go in them.

Comment: Worked for me.  A bit scary at first because you have to do a pull and it gets ALL the files.

Answer (score 42):

As an aside, apart from the answer by mipadi (which should work by the way), you should know that doing:

```
git branch -D master
git checkout master
```

also does exactly what you want without `having to redownload everything` (your quote paraphrased). That is because your local repo contains a copy of the remote repo (and that copy is not the same as your local directory, it is not even the same as your checked out branch).

Wiping out a branch is perfectly safe and reconstructing that branch is very fast and involves no network traffic. Remember, git is primarily a local repo by design. Even remote branches have a copy on the local. There's only a bit of metadata that tells git that a specific local copy is actually a remote branch. In git, all files are on your hard disk all the time.

If you don't have any branches other than master, you should:

```
git checkout -b 'temp'
git branch -D master
git checkout master
git branch -D temp
```

Comment: But how does that tells apart commits made locally from commits made at origin? In fact, it tells me that `Cannot delete the branch 'master' which you are currently on.`

Comment: 1. Basically all commits are the same, regardless if they are made locally or at origin. What's important is that the histories are synchronized correctly. Your local commit will only exist at origin after you pushed them and by default git will refuse the push if the history at origin may end up in a state that doesn't make sense.

Comment: 2. Of course you cannot delete the branch that is currently checked out. To delete master, check out another branch first. Of if there is no other branch simply create a temporary one: `git checkout -b temp;git branch -D master;git checkout master;git branch -D temp`

Comment: Also note about what I said about your local copy of the remote repo being different: git will not allow you to edit or even view files in your copy of the remote branch. It will only allow you to create another branch from the remote branch which you can then view and edit. By convention, this local branch have the same name as the remote branch. You are partially right in that `origin/master` is on your local machine. That's your local (full) copy of the remote branch. The real remote branch is `origin master`.

Comment: This worked for me. Maybe the `git branch -D master` was not necessary though, since as pointed out it generates an error.

Comment: `git checkout -b 'temp'` creates a branch called `'temp'`, not `temp`.

Comment: @Nyerguds I don't know what shell you are using on what OS because I have not used Windows in over 10 years and don't know Powershell syntax but normally `'` is part of the shell syntax and `git checkout -b 'temp'` will create a branch called `temp` not `'temp'`. You may be thinking of `git checkout -b "'temp'"` or `git  checkout -b '\'temp\''`. Of course, this is true for Linux and Mac OS. As I said, I don't know about Windows.

Comment: I executed the command on Windows, and it literally told me there was no branch called `temp` when I executes the 4th command. I had to give the literal text `'temp'` to delete the branch made with that command. The only valid quotes on Window for surrounding arguments are double quotes. But this branch name contains no spaces or anything, so there's no point in adding the quotes anyway; you should just leave it off in your answer.

Answer (score 23):

What I do is I try to reset hard to HEAD. This will wipe out all the local commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Comment: This is the best answer, that really worked. Discarded all local commits and reset to HEAD. Whats the use of ^ char?

Comment: @karim the '^' is probably regex stuff, which probably something quite deep that I don't know or read long time ago in the manual file.. sorry man :)

Comment: Late, but the `^` represents the parent commit, so resetting to `HEAD^` discards uncommitted changes and moves the branch to the previous commit, effectively "deleting" the most recent commit (although the commit still exists, the branch just doesn't point to it). The answer will have only one local commit and the rest are uncommitted changes. @karim @giang

Comment: According to [learngitbranching.js.org](https://learngitbranching.js.org/), the `^` operator references the parent of a commit. So, if one were to run `git checkout HEAD^^^`, it would checkout the point in time 3 commits 'above' HEAD on the git graph, if you will.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen instances where the remote became out of sync and needed to be updated. If a `reset --hard` or a `branch -D` fail to work, try

```
git pull origin
git reset --hard
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, a `reset --hard` works in this situation

Comment: Hi Charles, you're right that `reset --hard` should work here. However, I'm simply pointing out that it occasionally fails to reset the branch properly and a `git pull origin` will re-sync the remote and allow the `reset --hard` to function properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run

```
git fetch
```

To get all changes and then you will not receive message with "your branch is ahead".

Comment: Fetching has nothing to do with the asker's main problem, which is getting rid of local commits.

Comment: what if i have already committed files in local and then trying to fire mentioned command. It will show same error message. I tried git fetch and git fetch -p too. but showing same error

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a :

```
git checkout -b master
```

as git said that it doesn't exists, because it's been wipe with the

```
git -D master
```