# The command "git reset" will be implemented on local or remote?

Tags: git

I am still confused "git reset --hard HEAD" will be implemented on local or remote?

sorry for my ignorance, I am quite new to git.

Comment: Take a look at the [Progit book](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2) it should answer all of your questions.

Comment: local, git is always local except push and pull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on where you run the command, based on the fact you're new to git I assume you're talking about your local machine?
In that case the change only affects your **local** machine, for more information refer to [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting) resource.

Comment: If I use bitbucket to locate my repository, the git reset I implement on my computer will only affect my local changes?

Comment: Yes, `git reset --hard HEAD` actually means: "reset my changes and apply the last commit on the server as my current work tree" (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3882696/4814251) answer for more info)

Comment: @GSWV "last commit on the server" that you know of (since last pull or fetch)